# Display only one kind of the vowel

Tags: java

I need to display only one type of the vowel that have check from a string 
but it keeps on display the repeated vowel.

**Input:** I am in you all day and wathc you over.

**Output:**
Vowels : I a o u e
Consonants : m n y l d w t h c r

this means it will display the vowel that was used in the sentence.
the same goes for the consonant

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class aaaa {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
System.out.println ("Enter a string:");
String s = input.nextLine();

char[] sChars = s.toCharArray();
char[] vowels = {'a','e','i','o','u','A','E','I','O','U'}; 
char[] consonant = {'b','c','d','f','g','h','k','j','l','m','n','p','q','r','s','t','x','v','w','y','z'};

for (int j = 0 ; j < sChars.length ; j++ ) {   
    for (int i = 0; i < vowels.length ; i++ ) {
        if ( sChars[j] == vowels[i]) {
            System.out.print(vowels[i]+ " ");
        }

    }
}
System.out.print("\n");
for(int m = 0 ; m < sChars.length ; m++){
    for(int n = 0; n < consonant.length ; n++){
        if ( sChars[m] == consonant[n]){
            System.out.print(consonant[n]+" ");
        }
    }
}

  }

}
```

Comment: So what's the actual...problem here?

Comment: Can you post what your current input is and what the erroneous output is.

Comment: Input : This is round and yours.
Output:
Vowel : i i o u a o u

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
System.out.println("Vowels: " + s.toLowerCase().replaceAll("[^aeiou]|(.)(?=.*\\1)", "") 
+ "\nConsonants: " + s.toLowerCase().replaceAll("[aeiou]|(.)(?=.*\\1)", ""));
```

This gets the entire job done in one line by using regex to select the characters of interest to delete.

FYI, the regex `[aeiou]|(.)(?=.*\1)` means "any vowel, or any character that does not reappear". The first match of an alternation stops there, that's why I didn't need to code the character class for consonants in the right hand side - the dot will only match for non-vowels.

A similar approach is used for printing vowels, except it's a *negated* character class.

Comment: i have tried your code but it displays multiple output
example:
Input : Elf and tiger
Output : 
Vowels : eai
Vowels : eai
Vowels : eai
Vowels : eai

Comment: @EdzelAce The code is fine. You must be executing it a loop. I think you've missed the point: This one line can replace your entire program after `String s = input.nextLine();`

Answer (score 0):

There are way more efficient ways of doing this, but I will try to change as little of your solution as possible.

Keep track of the letters already printed, and don't print them a second time:

```
char[] vowels = {'A','E','I','O','U'}; 
char[] consonant = {'B','C','D','F','G','H','K','J','L','M','N','P','Q','R','S','T','X','V','W','Y','Z'};

// create a collection to store the letters already used
List<Character> lettersUsed = new ArrayList<Character>();
for (int j = 0 ; j < sChars.length ; j++ ) {   
    for (int i = 0; i < vowels.length ; i++ ) {
        if ( Character.toUpperCase(sChars[j]) == vowels[i]) {
            // if the collection of used letters does not contain this one
            if(!lettersUsed.contains(Character.toUpperCase(sChars[j]))) {
                System.out.print(sChars[j]+ " ");
                // add this letter to the collection of letters used
                lettersUsed.add(Character.toUpperCase(sChars[j]));
            }
            // now that you've found a match, break out of the inner loop
            break;
        }            
    }
}
System.out.print("\n");
for(int m = 0 ; m < sChars.length ; m++){
    for(int n = 0; n < consonant.length ; n++){
        if ( Character.toUpperCase(sChars[m]) == consonant[n]){
            // if the collection of used letters does not contain this one
            if(!lettersUsed.contains(Character.toUpperCase(sChars[m]))) {
                System.out.print(sChars[m]+" ");
                // add this letter to the collection of letters used
                lettersUsed.add(Character.toUpperCase(sChars[m]));
            }
            // now that you've found a match, break out of the inner loop
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: hi, i have tried using your code but it gives error in line List<Char> lettersUsed = new ArrayList<Char>(); still gives even i already imported ArrayList

Comment: hi i have your code running but there is a problem
Example input:
World is in war
Output : Vowel : o i a
Constant : W r l d s n w r

Comment: Edited. Code now stores upper case character in list and checks if upper case character exists in list.

Comment: i can't seem know why the line " lettersUsed.add(Character.valueOf(sChars[j]).toUpperCase());" gives error do i have to import something?

Comment: My apologies - I just loaded the code into my IDE and have fixed the errors. You will need to import List and ArrayList.

Comment: Sorry could you help me for one more time, example : Input word : World is Above Output : Vowels - o i A e  Consonants - W R L D B V
the problem is that Consonants output should be Consonant - W r l d b v ... and i can't figure out what to do now